# How do I draw a single Triangle with XNA and fill it with a Texture?

Tags: c#, textures, xna-4.0

I'm trying to wrap my head around:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb196409.aspx

I'm trying to create a method in XNA that renders a single Triangle, then later make a method that takes a list of Triangles and renders them also. But it isn't working. I'm not understanding what all the things does and there's not enough information.

### My methods:

```
// Triangle is a struct with A, B, C (didn't include) A, B, C = Vector3

public static void Render(GraphicsDevice device, List<Triangle> triangles, Texture2D texture)
{
    foreach (Triangle triangle in triangles)
    {
        Render(device, triangle, texture);
    }
}

public static void Render(GraphicsDevice device, Triangle triangle, Texture2D texture)
{
    BasicEffect _effect = new BasicEffect(device);
    _effect.Texture = texture;
    _effect.VertexColorEnabled = true;

    VertexPositionColor[] _vertices = new VertexPositionColor[3];

    _vertices[0].Position = triangle.A;
    _vertices[1].Position = triangle.B;
    _vertices[2].Position = triangle.B;

    foreach (var pass in _effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
    {
        pass.Apply();

        device.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives<VertexPositionColor>
        (
            PrimitiveType.TriangleList,
            _vertices,
            0,
            _vertices.Length,
            new int[] { 0, 1, 2 }, // example has something similiar, no idea what this is
            0,
            3 // 3 = gives me an error, 1 = works but no results
        );
    }

}
```

---

### Now my method looks like this, according to your recommendations:

```
    public static void Render(GraphicsDevice device, Triangle triangle, Color color)
    {
        BasicEffect _effect = new BasicEffect(device);
        _effect.Texture = ColorToTexture(device, color, 1, 1);
        _effect.TextureEnabled = true;
        //_effect.VertexColorEnabled = true;

        VertexPositionTexture[] _vertices = new VertexPositionTexture[3];

        _vertices[0].Position = triangle.A;
        _vertices[1].Position = triangle.B;
        _vertices[2].Position = triangle.C;

        foreach (var pass in _effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
        {
            pass.Apply();

            device.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives<VertexPositionTexture>
            (
                PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip, // same result with TriangleList
                _vertices,
                0,
                _vertices.Length,
                new int[] { 0, 1, 2 },
                0,
                1
            );
        }

    }
```

and my method that creates a texture from color (tried this with single spriteBatch.Draw() = works)

```
    public static Texture2D ColorToTexture(GraphicsDevice device, Color color, int width, int height)
    {
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(device, 1, 1);
        texture.SetData<Color>(new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color[] { color });

        return texture;
    }
```

and in my Draw method in Main Game:

```
Render(GraphicsDevice, new Triangle(new Vector3(50, 50, 0), new Vector3(100, 100, 0), new Vector3(150, 50, 0)), Color.Green);
```

= no triangle on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should rather use [VertexPositionTexture structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.vertexpositiontexture.aspx) instead of VertexPoisitionColor to define vertex and texture coordinates. Also set: `_effect.TextureEnabled` to true.

And to your DrawUserIndexedPrimitives call:

- fifth parameter is indeces to the array of vertices. So you render triangle defined by vertices _vertices[0], _vertices[1], _vertices[2].
- Last parameter is number of primitives to render - you have only one triangle with 3 vertices. So you should really pass 1.

As r2d2rigo wrote: your two vertices are the same point:

```
_vertices[1].Position = triangle.B;
_vertices[2].Position = triangle.B;
```

**UPDATE:**

Vertex coordinates have to be in range <-1;1>. 0,0 is center point of the screen (window).

Comment: Still nothing. I pass this to the method: Render(GraphicsDevice, new Triangle(new Vector3(50, 50, 0), new Vector3(100, 100, 0), new Vector3(150, 50, 0)), Color.Green); If I pass Color.Green instead of texture, it creates a texture (1x1 texture) of a single color. This way:  Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(device, 1, 1); texture.SetData<Color>(new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color[] { color }); Still nothing. I haven't set the camera to be anything but default, so shouldn't there be something? It shows nothing.

Comment: Yes. You should set View, World and Projection matrices of BasicEffect. World matrix can be just eye matrix. View matrix can be created using method Matrix.CreateLookAt(From, To, Up) - look from 0,0,0 to your triangle with up vector equal to Vector3.Up. Projection can be created as: Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4, GameObject.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.AspectRatio, 1, 1000);

Comment: Ok. I've tried this, but I don't get it to work anyhow. I don't want 3D view at all, I just wanted to draw triangles first. So my Matrixes looks like this: _effect.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4, device.Viewport.AspectRatio, 1, 1000);
            _effect.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(0, 0, 0)); _effect.World = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(0, 0, 0));

Are there anything I need to set in spriteBatch or do I even use that?

Comment: Ok. So if you want only 2D, then those matrices are really needless :) But in that case, your triangle coordinates should be in range <-1;1>, which is screen coordinates. See this example: http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series1/The_first_triangle.php

Comment: I'm going to need those when I move the camera, but that's a different issue I'm more familiar with. Don't I need BasicEffect (or can't I use it?) for 2D graphics too?

Comment: I got it to work with that example (tried it earlier but had to have Effect visible), although I have no clue as to why the Triangle is centered on the screen? It seems less flexible.

Comment: I mean, I have a screen of say 640x480 and I want to place a triangle within that position but with -0.5f and 0.0f as coordinates I get confused by the placements. It can't be limited to the size of the window, because that'll change. Say I want my triangle to start at (X=100, Y=100) and left corner at (X=50, Y=150) and right corner at (X=150, Y=150) and then also be able to move the Triangle wherever I like, values like 0.5f and such makes no sense.

Comment: ...or if I want what I render not to be limited by the screen size, that I have a camera that moves.

Comment: Then you have to recompute it according to your screen size: device.Viewport ... from your coordinates to screen coordinates.

Comment: Ok. I understood that 0.0f = center of screen in (X, Y, Z) coordinate. That value 0.0f = still center of screen, although I move my viewport -100 in each direction and the value is still 0.0f it will still render at the center of the screen? So, if I move Viewport (ScreenWidth/Height = 640/480) - 640 in width, the value 0.0f will become 1.5f? 640 + (640/2). Well, I think I understand it if that's the case. I'll mark the discussion as solved and I'll experiment. Any suggestions on how to render shapes with more points or unlimited points? In 2D. Or do I have to combine triangles?

Comment: You can of course draw shapes with more points, but you have to create triangle list or triangle strip from them: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.primitivetype.aspx But this is other question and I think that new thread should be created ;)

Answer (score 0):

The code you pasted should be drawing a line because you are assigning `_vertices[1]` and `_vertices[2]` the same triangle vertex. Fix it and change the last paramenter in `DrawUserIndexedPrimitives` to 1, since it's the number of primitives (in your case, triangles) that you are going to draw with that call.